# Select specific item from list

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing, outofrangeexception

I am running some functions against a csv file. I call to a specific column and split the text:

```
 with open('lasty.csv','rb') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     for column in reader:
          entry = column[7].split(" ")[4]
```

An example of column 7 would look like:

```
    ['Withdrawal', 'Debit', '', '', "MITTCHELL'S", 'FISH', 'M', '', '', '', '', 'location', 'location', '', 'location']
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
    entry = column[7].split(" ")[4]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

However if I run:

```
  entry = column[7].split(" ")[0]
```

It works with out error, but after [0] it gives me the same error.

Thank you in advanced.

EDIT:

column 7 before splitting looks like:

```
    "Withdrawal Debit   MITTCHELL'S FISH M     WINTER PARK  FLUS"
```

In this case I am looking to grab "MITTCHELL'S" which when the column is split is in the [4] or 5th place.

Comment: The problem is that the eighth column doesn't have 8 space-separated items. It could perhaps be `"a b c d"`, which would explain why you are getting an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row` is an *individual* row from your input CSV and *already* split into columns.

You are trying to split an empty string in this case:

```
>>> ''.split(' ')
['']
```

Just use `entry = row[4]` instead:

```
 for row in reader:
      entry = row[4]
```

Comment: @JohnK: You need to double check that your line is not empty. You can use `str.split()` *without* arguments to split on variable-width whitespace and avoid all those empty strings.

Comment: That does help remove the extra spaces however I still get the index error. I would now need to call to [2] or the third item. any thoughts

Comment: As I said, your `row[7]` is, for certain values of `row`, *not what you think it is*. You have more than one row in your CSV file, perhaps one matches your expectations, but there appears at least one other where your column does not have enough whitespace to create that many values.

Comment: @JohnK: Your error can **only** occur if you are splitting a string that does not have enough white-space separated words in it. That could be an empty string, or it could be a string with just one or two words in it. I understand that each row has a column 7 that is one string that you want to split on whitespace, then get the 3rd element.

Comment: I understand now you are saying that the is a row that does not have an item [2].... you would be correct! Thank you for your patience.